# Grep first line which contain a date

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm trying to fetch the first line in a log file which contain a date.
Here is an example of the log file :

```
SOME
LOG


2021-1-1 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC1 
2021-1-4 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC2
2021-1-5 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC3
2021-1-5 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC4
```

In this context I need to get the following line:

```
2021-1-1 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC1
```

An other log file example :

```
SOME
LOG


21-1-3 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC1 
21-1-3 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC2
21-1-4 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC3
21-1-5 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC4
```

I need to fetch :

```
21-1-3 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC1
```

At the moment I tried the following command :

```
cat /path/to/file | grep "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" | tail -1
cat /path/to/file | grep "$(date +"%-Y-%-m-%-d")" | tail -1
cat /path/to/file | grep -E "[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]" | tail -1
```

Comment: `grep -E -m1 '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]-[0-9]+ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+' /path/to/file`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't find on the second log file

Comment: For the frst line you want head, not tail.

Comment: and `date '+%Y-%m-%d'` will print a 4-digit year and a zero-padded 2-digit month.

Comment: Right, I only tested with one of them. You need `^[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})?-[0-9]-[0-9]+ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+`. [Demo](https://ideone.com/LL6wnu) ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lAgZEx/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the comment, I'll use **RavinderSingh13** solution :)

Comment: what are **ALL** possible date format you'll have to deal with? is it just these 2 or are there more?  is there a general format that matches all formats (eg, `#-#-# #:#:#` )?

Comment: @markp-fuso Only the format in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following. This will find the matched regex first line and exit from program, which will be faster since its NOT reading whole Input_file.

```
awk '
/^[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})?-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+/{
  print
  exit
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using sed, being not too concerned about exactly how many digits are present:

```sh
sed -En '/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[|]/ {p; q}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -m1 '^[0-9]' file1
2021-1-1 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC1

$ grep -m1 '^[0-9]' file2
21-1-3 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC1
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `grep` with `-m 1` (to exit after finding first match):

```sh
grep -m1 -E '^([0-9]+-){2}[0-9]+ ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file1
2021-1-1 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC1

grep -m1 -E '^([0-9]+-){2}[0-9]+ ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file2
21-1-3 21:50:19.0|LOG|DESC1
```

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` works with either GNU or POSIX sed:

```
sed -nE '/^[[:digit:]]{2,4}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}/{p;q;}' file
```

But `awk`, with the same BRE, is probably better:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]{2,4}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}/{print; exit}' file
```